# How to find the key of the last array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash that has an array value:

```
some_attributes['variants']
# =>
# [
#   [["variantCode", "0715839001002"], ["sizeCode", "002"], ["sizeName", "XS"]],
#   [["variantCode", "0715839001003"], ["sizeCode", "003"], ["sizeName", "S"]],
#   [["variantCode", "0715839001004"], ["sizeCode", "004"], ["sizeName", "M"]],
#   [["variantCode", "0715839001005"], ["sizeCode", "005"], ["sizeName", "L"]]
# ]
```

I am expecting in a new array the keys of each "sizeName":

```
['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L']
```

I tried like this:

```
some_attributes['variants'[[['sizeName']]]]

some_attributes['variants'].select{|size| sizeName["sizeName"]}
```

But I can't find the solution. Any tricks?

Comment: You have not shown your expected result. The question is not clear. I managed to answer only by guessing what you want.

Comment: @sawa I edited the question, Tiw answered it. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you could turn the variants into hashes.

```
some_attributes = {
  "variants" => [
    [["variantCode", "0715839001002"], ["sizeCode", "002"], ["sizeName", "XS"]],
    [["variantCode", "0715839001003"], ["sizeCode", "003"], ["sizeName", "S"]],
    [["variantCode", "0715839001004"], ["sizeCode", "004"], ["sizeName", "M"]],
    [["variantCode", "0715839001005"], ["sizeCode", "005"], ["sizeName", "L"]]
  ]
}

variants = some_attributes['variants'].map(&:to_h)
variants.map { |variant| variant['sizeName'] }
=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Then it's easier to do something like:

```
large_variant = variants.find { |variant| variant['sizeName'] == 'L' }
puts large_variant['variantCode']
# outputs:
# 0715839001005
```

Or to just get what you wanted, simply:

```
some_attributes['variants'].map { |a| a.last.last }
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
some_attributes['variants'].map{|a| a[-1][1]}
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Where the first `-1` is the index of the last of element of the 1st dimension.
And the second `1` is simply the second index of the 2nd demension,
 -- which in this case, is in effect the same of another `-1` / last index.

I.E. below is the same in effect:

```
some_attributes['variants'].map{|a| a[-1][-1]}
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

To increase the legibility:

```
some_attributes['variants'].map{|a| a.last.last}
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Not only this notation is more intuitive, but it also runs faster, check [iGian's Benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961103/5403468) below:)

Comment: Thanks @Tiw, it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity:

```
some_attributes['variants'].map { |(_, _), (_, _), (_, e)| e }
#⇒ ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]

some_attributes['variants'].map(&:flatten).map(&:last)
#⇒ ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Comment: You could make the first more general by writing the block `{ |*,(_, e)| e }`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, other option:

```
some_attributes["variants"].map(&:last).map(&:last)
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Also

```
some_attributes["variants"].transpose.last.transpose.last
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

Or even a mix:

```
some_attributes["variants"].map(&:last).transpose.last
#=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]
```

---

**A benchmark of the methods posted**

```
require 'benchmark'
n = 5000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("tiw_____") { n.times { some_attributes['variants'].map{|a| a[-1][1]} } }
  x.report("kimmo___") { n.times { some_attributes['variants'].map { |a| a.last.last } } }
  x.report("Aleksei1") { n.times { some_attributes['variants'].map { |(_, _), (_, _), (_, e)| e } } }
  x.report("igian1__") { n.times { some_attributes["variants"].map(&:last).map(&:last) } }
  x.report("igian3__") { n.times { some_attributes["variants"].map(&:last).transpose.last } }
  x.report("igian2__") { n.times { some_attributes["variants"].transpose.last.transpose.last } }
  x.report("Aleksei2") { n.times { some_attributes['variants'].map(&:flatten).map(&:last) } }
end
```

One result (each run results change a bit):

```
#        user     system      total        real
# tiw_____  0.007577   0.000078   0.007655 (  0.007709)
# kimmo___  0.003979   0.000086   0.004065 (  0.004070)
# Aleksei1  0.008227   0.000158   0.008385 (  0.008542)
# igian1__  0.008080   0.000132   0.008212 (  0.008220)
# igian2__  0.011956   0.000168   0.012124 (  0.012571)
# igian3__  0.013975   0.000122   0.014097 (  0.014261)
# Aleksei2  0.054203   0.002921   0.057124 (  0.059449)
```

Comment: Two `map`'s in a row is always a red flag to me. Consider instead `some_attributes["variants"].map { |a| a.last.last }  #=> ["XS", "S", "M", "L"]`. I don't know as a fact , however, that a single `map` with a lengthier block calculation is generally faster than two successive `map`'s. It would be interesting to see some benchmarks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Actually, I was just curious to find alternative ways to get the result. But your point is always in the right direction. Edited with a benchmark, the method you suggested (posted by Kimmo) is twice as faster.